# Code with BoF that cannot be detected by symbolic execution

Tags: vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners

I am having troubles finding and understanding when symbolic execution fail.

From my understanding tools like PathCrawler use symbolic execution. I gave it this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vulnerable_function(char *input) {
  char buffer[10];
  strcpy(buffer, input);
  printf("Input: %s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <input>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

It just detected some crashes because of the if statement but not the BoF. I don't understand why.

PS: I am taking the example of BoF but if you have examples with Use After Free it will much appreciated.